# How to set hardcoded value on inputType 'choiceset' in Teams Manifest?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I wonder if there is a workaround to set choices for input type choiceset in MS Teams Manifest

A sample that you can set on MS Teams Manifest file.

```
 {
    "name": "options",
    "title": "Options",
    "description": "Demo Options",
    "inputType": "choiceset"
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found the answer on the internet but I discover the answer when I tried to manipulate the Teams Manifest and I found out that there is an Intillecense for *choices* which is an array.

Here is the sample Manifest JSON.

```
{
    "name": "option",
    "title": "opption",
    "description": "Demo Option",
    "inputType": "choiceset",
    "choices": [
       {
          "title": "option1",
          "value": "1"
       },
       {
          "title": "option2",
          "value": "2"
       }
    ]
}
```